# Adding readymade plugin to cloud service of phonegap

Tags: cordova, build, cloud

I am new to Phonegap development. Please tell me how to use readymade plugins in phonegap build service?

As per my knowledge we can add only HTML, JavaScript and CSS files. But what about plugins?

Note: I wanted to do barcode scanner app for android using build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the supported plugins [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins). You will see the documentation there too. You need a line of code to add to the config.xml to make the plugin work. Some plugins might need more stuff to do.